# what if I just simply rename of a file instead of using right to left override

Tags: spoofing

I'm browsing the ATT&CK and I understand the meaning of right-to-left override that it is using non-printing unicode character, but what is the different if I just simply rename a file like this: `file.txt.exe` in cmd, instead of inserting unicode to make it like this: `filetxt.exe`, showing the file in the properties between the 2 results of inserting unicode and simply rename into file.txt.exe it does not show any different, furthermore if you rename a file in cmd for `file.txt.exe`, it will looks like a normal file, because in the GUI does not show the real extension of the file if you do not look at the properties of the file

Answer (score 1):

If the user has file extensions shown, then the double extension would be visible and obvious. Otherwise, the ".txt" will show up and thus stand out, since it would be the only file with a visible extension.

Comment: I create new txt file and I dont see it has visible extension